# How to dynamically change pagination based on a certain condition using Java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pagination

On an angular app i am doing the below on the Client side:

I am getting list of tiles to display as a response from rest service, now i am dividing them into set of 3 tiles for a page. So if i get 5, my logic divides them to 2 sets - page 1 with 3 tiles and page 2 with 2 tiles.

After this, i need to make another rest service for each of the above tile to fetch the content to display on the tile. If my content fetch fails i am removing the specific tile from the list.

I wanted to know how do i update my pagination logic from the initial step, since i already divided tiles into pages.

I am following the above logic, doing pagination initially to avoid delay in trying to fetch all content and then trying to display the page to the user.

I am looking for a JS solution to handle this.

I am using Angular 1.4 stack for front end.

Comment: I have seen APIs that already returns the data 'paginated', which means if the response is too big it only delivers a part of it, indicating which page it corresponds to and how many pages are left, you could possibly make your logic display the available pages to the user and when he selects it the page makes a request to the server for the specific page's data.

Comment: Hi Arthur, back-end delivers certain meta-data, now the browser has to fetch some content from a service to display on the tile, i am trying to cover the failure scenarios - if that service fails, i need to suppress the specific tile and move forward with displaying the rest of the tiles on the page and update pagination accordingly

Comment: for example, fetch 3 pages, if all page calls succeeds render all 3 pages making 1 separate call to service backend for content. If 1 fails, collapse that box while keeping the others, what if page 2 (which is in the middle) fails ? Collapse 2 and all pages after 2 (to no make the UI display inconsistent paging info), these are just my suggestions